# Why does my Git branches always show as one line in visualization?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a local repo and I tried to create some branches here. I expect that it will look something like this.[image: Every branch has its own line and all it merge into master line]

But in my VS Code I get this:

[image]

I created a new test branch and one commit in it. But it is not displayed as a separate line,but is shown with the same master line. I think it's wrong, can I fix it?

Comment: Which commit you have pushed and is displayed on the same line?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen, the last. It names "asfa"

Comment: you have create this `test`-branch like `git checkout -b test` and after you have `commit` and `push`?

Comment: Add another commit to master. That'll "fix it".

Comment: @krisz, thanks, now it works

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually broken.

Consider this history, where newer commits are listed before older ones:

```
    o   <-- branch_B
    |
o   o      [branch_A ends here, on the left]
 \ /
  o
  |
  o
  :
  :
```

Here each round `o` represents some commit.  You can see that we have two branches that diverge from a single shared stream-of-commits, like a road that forks.  Clearly we have to distinguish between the two forks.

But now consider this one:

```
    o   <-- branch_B
    |
    o
   /
  o   <-- branch_A
  |
  o
  :
  :
```

This is the same history, except the "road that forks" just ends at the point where `branch_B` keeps going.  (Though, unlike the naming conventions for *roads*, the commits that are at `branch_A` and on down are on *both* branches.)

There's no real reason to draw in the kink here, though:

```
  o   <-- branch_B
  |
  o
  |
  o   <-- branch_A
  |
  o
  :
  :
```

is the same graph.